# Как вернуть кол-во файлов и папок?

Tags: java

Всем привет!)
Мне необходимо вернуть количество папок по указанному пути . Но почему-то метод `amountOfUsers = Files.walk(pathToRootFolder, 1).filter(Files::isDirectory).count();` первым элементом возвращает мне и саму директорию в которой я считываю кол-во папок . Как это исправить?

[image]

И вопрос номер 2 . Я так же должен считать файлы из папки и вернуть их имена , но при считывании мне возвращает еще и файл .DS_Store (он походу создается автоматом когда создается папка). Есть ли возможность кинуть в игнор допустим это имя файла?
Использовал такой вот код:

```
pathStream.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользовались когда-нибудь `Git`? Если пользовались, то наверняка знаете, что там есть файл `.gitignore`, в который можно записывать в строчку файлы/папки, которые следует игнорировать в формате `Regex`.

Сделайте также.

**Файл .ignore**

```
^.+Task repository$
^.DS_Store$
```

**Метод для считывания файла c игнорируемым объектами**

```
public List<Pattern> getIgnored() throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get("./.ignore"))
            .map(Pattern::compile)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Метод проверки имени директории/файла на наличие в списке игнорирования**

```
public boolean checkIgnore(String checkedOb) throws IOException {
    for (Pattern ignoredPattern : getIgnored()) {
        if (ignoredPattern.matcher(checkedOb).find()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Далее, в методе **.filter()** теперь указывайте условие не только *Files.isDirectory()*, а ещё и *checkIgnore()*

P.S. Естественно данный код можно рефакторить. Например, убрать считывание файла с игнорируемыми объектами при каждом обращении к методу *checkIgnore()*. Я просто дал Вам идею.